# REPL for Capybara

Tags: capybara, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to write some capybara cucumber scripts for my ROR app and find it very hard to get the scripts right by making change and running the full feature every time.

Is there a REPL (Read Eval Print Loop) for Capybara so that I can test small chunks of code for correctness faster?

Comment: Have you looked into Guard and Spork? There's a write up about it here http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-guard. It's witten for rspec but should apply for cucumber as well.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, my teammate found it... We can use irb and load capybara, then we can visit a page and do all the capybara pattern matching to our hearts content!

```
    irb -r rubygems -r capybara -r capybara/dsl
    > Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
    > include Capybara::DSL
    > page = Capybara.page
    > page.visit("http://someurl.in")
```

Comment: This is great! I wanted to do this in the rails console so I could set up user objects and such:

rails c\n\nrequire 'capybara/dsl'\nCapybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome\ninclude Capybara::DSL\n\nCapybara.app_host = 'localhost:3000/'\npage = Capybara.page\nvisit '/'